# How to have a header routing logic with nginx ingress-controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, routes, http-headers, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to achieve a header routing ingress rule with nginx. Why ? Because *the same path* should go to *different backend* based on *headers*. Here what i've tried:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-mutli-back
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      set $dataflag 0;

      if ( $http_content_type ~ "multipart\/form-data.*" ){
      set $dataflag 1;
      }

      if ( $dataflag = 1 ){
      set $service_name "backend-data";
      }

spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-default
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

But the logs of nginx output this error:

```
unknown directive "set $service_name backend-data" in /tmp/nginx-cfg864446123:1237
```

which seems unlogic to me... If I check the configuration generated by nginx, each rule generate a location with something like this at the begining:

```
[...]
       location ~* "^/api" {

            set $namespace      "my-namespace";
            set $ingress_name   "api-multi-back";
            set $service_name   "backend-default";
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong ? Isn't it possible to redefine **service_name** variable with annotation **configuration-snippet** ? Is there any other method ?

Edit: My error on nginx side was due to the lack of exact spaces between *set $service_name* and *backend-data*. Then nginx generated correctly the configuration but it still not routing to another kubernetes service.

Answer (score 3):

You got bitten by a YAML-ism:

The indentation of your 2nd `if` block isn't the same as the indentation of the others, and thus YAML thinks you are starting a new key under `annotations:`

You have

```yaml
metadata:
  name: api-mutli-back
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      set $dataflag 0;

      if ( $http_content_type ~ "multipart\/form-data.*" ){
      set $dataflag 1;
      }

     if ( $dataflag = 1 ){
     set $service_name "backend-data"
     }
```

but you should have:

```
metadata:
  name: api-mutli-back
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      set $dataflag 0;

      if ( $http_content_type ~ "multipart\/form-data.*" ){
      set $dataflag 1;
      }

      if ( $dataflag = 1 ){
      set $service_name "backend-data"
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake when reformatting my code block.

Be that as it may, it doesn't seems to me possible that YAML interpret it as a key as there is no semicolon. In addition, the error output is about nginx, not YAML.

Comment: Ok, then that's the other point you overlooked: the final `set` statement is missing its `;` statement terminator, unless you just neglected to post that in your question body, too

Comment: Yes, that's another typo, my bad. But that's not the issue.

Comment: @Kelindil, any lucky with this issue?

Comment: @Z.Liu Unfortunaly, no... I was in search of a built-in and elegant solution with nginx Ingress but I was in a hurry to resolve my issue. Then I've added a nginx pod to do the routing internally (easiest solution).