# How to redirect URL based on http header in nginx ingress?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

My requests are being proxied through Cloudflare which sets a header indicating the country in a http header based on the IP address. I want to redirect the requests with certain paths based on this header in Nginx ingress controller. How do I do this?

Comment: Hello, could you clarify if you are trying to "rewrite" the request by a header directed to one svc  or are you trying to route this requests to the different svc's by header? Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223733/how-to-make-nginx-redirect-based-on-the-value-of-a-header . Also as more of a pointer that a solution, Traefik and Ambassador have an option to run header based routing.

Comment: Thank you @Dawid. I’m looking to rewrite requests to bunch of SVCs based on header. The answer suggested in that question is how I’m doing it currently in Nginx. But was wondering how to achieve it in `Ingress` resource definitions. Looks like I need to define a map with redirect URLs in the `http-snippet` config in the Nginx Ingress Controller and then use either `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` or `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` in the `Ingress resource` to do the redirection. Didn’t know Traefik and Ambassador have this option. Thanks, will check them out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Currently `Ingress` resource definition for `nginx-ingress` does not support header based routing.**

I found a **workaround** to route a request by it's header (I've included the steps below) with following annotation:

```yaml
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($http_LocationHeader = "PL") { proxy_pass http://goodbye-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5678; }
```

Other possible solutions/workarounds:

- Use `Traefik`: *[Docs.traefik.io: Routing: Routers](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/)*
- Use `Ambassador`: *[Getambassador.io: Docs: Using: Headers](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/using/headers/headers/)*
- Use `Istio`: [Istio.io: Traffic management: Request routing](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/)
- Route the traffic from `nginx-ingress` to nginx pod/deployment/daemonset with header based routing logic included: *[Stackoverflow.com: How to have a header routing logic with nginx ingress-controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806531/12257134)*
   (last comment under the answer)

---

As for a **workaround**:

Assuming that (for example purposes):

- There are 2 Deployments: `hello`,`goodbye`
- Both are associated with their services with names: `hello-service`, `goodbye-service`

The `Ingress` resource will be configured in a way that `hello` should always answer, but with the addition of `configuration-snippet` the traffic will be redirected to `goodbye`.

Responses of this deployments:

```
|     hello      |    goodbye     |
|----------------|----------------|
| Hello, world!  | Hello, world!  |
| Version: 2.0.0 | Version: 1.0.0 | # notice the version
```

Example of `hello` deployment with a service attached to it:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
    - name: hello-port
      port: 5678 # IMPORTANT
      targetPort: 50001
  type: NodePort
```

To get the `goodbye` deployment please substitute the `hello` for `goodbye` and change the image version to `1.0`.

Ingress definition to reroute the request by a header looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress 
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($http_LocationHeader = "PL") { proxy_pass http://goodbye-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5678; }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service 
          servicePort: hello-port
```

By default this Ingress definition without the `configuration-snippet` would always route the traffic to `hello-service` and then to `hello` pods. By adding the:

```yaml
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($http_LocationHeader = "PL") { proxy_pass http://goodbye-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5678; }
```

it will check if the header named `LocationHeader` is present and if it matches `PL`. If it does it will send the request to `goodbye-service` by it's DNS name.

Focusing on:

- `http://goodbye-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5678`
- `http://service_name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:port` (dns name without values)

After applying this `Ingress` resource you should be able to send a request with `LocationHeader=PL` (with *[Postman](https://www.postman.com/)* for example) and get the response:

```sh
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: goodbye-5758448754-wr64c
```

> When I tried to use `map` directive I was getting following messages:
>
> - `nginx: [emerg] "map" directive is not allowed here in /tmp/nginx-OMMITED`

Comment: Thank you @Dawid for the detailed answer. I was able to achieve this using `configuration-snippet`. As for the map, it is not allowed in `server` and `location` contexts which is why you were seeing the error. It has to be injected using `http-snippet` while deploying the NGINX ingress controller.