# NGINX Ingress Routing based on Header

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have an nginx-ingress calling a custom `auth-service` before sending requests to the backend service, using this simple ConfigMap and Ingress:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  ...
data:
  global-auth-url: auth-service-url:8080/authenticate
  global-auth-method: GET
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  ...
spec:
  rules:
  - host: host1
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Now I need something different.

How can I send requests, all with the same "Host" header, through different flows, one with auth-service and connected to `backend-service1` and the other without any authentication and connecting to `backend-service2`?

To be clear, and using the custom header "Example-header: test"

1. If "Example-header" is "test", authenticate via my `auth-service` before sending to `backend-service`, as it's done now.
2. If "Example-header" is not defined, I want to send requests to a different backend service and do not use `auth-service` in the process.

I tried a couple of things, namely having 2 Ingresses, one with `global-auth-url` and the other with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-global-auth: "false"` but the auth-service is always called.

Can I do this with NGINX, or do I have to use Istio or Ambassador?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63374847/14484111

Comment: I tried that but it still makes a call to the `auth-service` that I want to avoid.

Comment: @JoãoPereira Did you try to implement the provided solution without `auth-service`? Just to check the possibility for Headers usage for redirection: with configuration-snippet and "test" in Header it connects to `backend-service1` and without "test" in Header to `backend-service2`  respectivly.

Answer (score 9):

One way you can achieve this behavior is by abusing the [canary feature](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary).

For your `backend-service`, create a normal Ingress, e. g.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-backend
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Create a second Ingress for you `auth-service` with enabled canary and set the header name and value, e. g.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-auth
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header: Example-header
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header-value: test
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: auth-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Now, every request with `Example-header: test` routes to `auth-service`. Any other value, e. g. `Example-header: some-value`, will **not** route to `auth-service` but rather go to your `backend-service`.

Comment: Note that [the documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary) states that a maximum of 1 canary is supported, so this cannot be used to support multiple API versions for exampe.

Comment: @malte.h Is it necessary to have the same set of paths in normal and canary ingress?

Comment: @Vikash I'm not sure. But I would assume that the paths do not have to be the same in both ingress resources.